# previous sunday date in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I've a requirement where I need to compare a column date with current date. If my column date > last sunday's date I need to populate a status. Here, am facing issues in calculating present week's sunday date.
I need to calculate Previous Sunday's date in Informatica expression transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about your requirement, however, you can always get the day and based on that subtract a fixed number of days to reach any sunday you want (present week or previous week). You should have a limited (7) set of IIF statements to achieve this.
Eg. If the day is 'Tuesday' (day of the current date) then subtract 2 from the date to get sunday date!

Answer (score 0):

You can write an expression as- `trunc(sysdate,'d')` in a variable port which is having datatype as date.

The `expression` would return the Sunday date of the current date. Then you can compare the two dates (your column date and the variable port date) and populate the status.

If you just want to verify the result of the expression `trunc(sysdate,'d')` you can fire the following query in the oracle db:

```
"select trunc(sysdate,'d') from dual"
```

result returned would be the latest Sunday date.

Comment: Hi Mr Rathore, welcome to StackOverflow! You answer is very unclear. I tried to edit it but had to abandon it as I was afraid I might not have correctly interpreted what you meant to say. Please consider revising it yourself to make it better understandable.